# How can two seemingly identical databases return results sorted by different columns?

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing

I've got a single query

```
SELECT r.id
     , r.account_id
     , r.name
     , r.bucket_id
     , r.description
     , r.development
     , r.created_at
     , r.priority
  FROM realms r
 WHERE r.account_id = 3;
```

I run it on two different tables with the same indexes, and one result is sorted by `r.id` and `r.created_at` (same order either way), and the other is sorted by `r.name`. How can this be?

Looking at it through the table inspector in MySQL Workbench, the indexes for both are:

```
+---------------------------+-------+-----+-----------------+
| key                       |Type   |Uni  | Columns         |
+ --------------------------+-------+-----+-----------------+
| PRIMARY                   | BTREE | YES | id              |
| realms_account_id_name_UQ | BTREE | YES | account_id,name |
| realms_account_id_IX      | BTREE | NO  | account_id      |
| realms_bucket_id_IX       | BTREE | NO  | bucket_id       |
+---------------------------+-------+-----+-----------------+
```

I thought it was the indexes that decided what order rows came in, and the screen doesn't even *blink* when I switch between the two. If the primary key for both of them is `id` why does one show results ordered by name?

Comment: Rows in sql tables have no inherent order, so the question is meaningless

Comment: Let's turn "meaningless" into a lesson on using `ORDER BY` and understanding how indexes do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT`, the system can do whatever it feels like.  Period.  Full stop.

Now, I will explain what *probably* happened.

First, the Optimizer will analyze the indexes, the datatypes, the statistics, etc, and decide how to execute the query.  You can get a peek into this operation by doing `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  It will say which index it is likely to use.

I see two indexes that are reasonable -- the two beginning with `account_id`.  Either one would be fine.  Probably the Optimizer had slightly different statistics on the two machine, leading it to pick one index on one machine, and the other on the other.

Analysis of using `INDEX(account_id, name)`.  That index is an ordered list of the pairs of account_ids and names.  On the machine where it used that index, it drilled down the BTree index to the first entry for `account_id = 3`, then scanned forward.  This gave you the results ordered by `name`.

Analysis of using `INDEX(account_id)`.  InnoDB, in order to find the data, tacks the `PRIMARY KEY` columns onto each secondary index.  So, that index is effectively `INDEX(account_id, id)`.  On the machine where it used that index, it drilled down the BTree index to the first entry for `account_id = 3`, then scanned forward.  This gave you the results ordered by `id`.

A third possibility is common and is worth noting.  If there are lots of rows with `account_id = 3`, the Optimizer would decide to eschew the index and simply read the data.  Since the data is stored according to the `PRIMARY KEY`, it would, again, deliver the rows in `id` order (but for a radically different reason).